# Blocked data after transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

I wanted to do some update on a table (which one we could name "table1") and I wanted to use a transaction because of our production server.

I wrote a script like this :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

UPDATE table1 SET ...

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ...
```

And as you can see I forgot the commit/rollback statement.

After that I wanted to do another select on this table and I got a query timeout error.

I guessed that my transaction was blocking my table so I did another time the exact same transaction but this time with a commit statement.

But my table still blocked and I don't know how to commit/rollback the first waiting transaction.

I also tried to write a new query with just "COMMIT TRANSACTION T1" but I got an error telling me that the COMMIT statement need a corresponding BEGIN statement.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session where you ran the first query is still active. If you ran this via SSMS then run the Commit\Rollback from there with that session. If you can't find it then use the Activity Monitor or sp_who2 or other type method to locate the session and kill it.

You cannot modify the transaction on another session.

Comment: I ran sp_who2 and it returned me only mine session with the status RUNNABLE and nothing in the BlkBy. Also I ran the first transaction in SSMS but I haven't any query which still running. If I just disconnect from the server It would stop the remaining transaction ?

Comment: If the table's still block then the session is still out there. The query won't be running, it will be active though. Look through ALL your SSMS tabs for the session at hand. When in doubt kill SSMS (thus rolling back the transaction). If that doesn't work then come back here.

Comment: Ok I just have 2 SMSS tabs active so I tried to quitSMSS instead. When I closed it, it said that there are transactions which still uncommitted and asked me if I want to commit them. I said no and my table is unlocked now ! Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear you're up and running again!